# flex blazeds spring exception translator

Tags: spring, apache-flex, exception, blazeds

I am using spring exception translator to wrap java exception into flex exception.

```
 public void testException()throws Exception{
       throw new Exception("my exception");
}
```

But for some reason, I am getting `IllegalAccessError`. The code sections are entering the testException and the Translator class.

**Question:**

Why it trying to get log target level? Can someone help me resolve this please.

Below is the lines from the log:

```
MyExceptionTranslatorImpl.translate()
class java.lang.IllegalAccessError  

MyExceptionTranslatorImpl.translate()
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method **flex.messaging.log.Log.getTargetLevel()S** from class flex.messaging.MessageException  

MyExceptionTranslatorImpl.translate()
tried to access method 
flex.messaging.log.Log.getTargetLevel()S from class flex.messaging.MessageException
[BlazeDS] tried to access method flex.messaging.log.Log.getTargetLevel()S from class flex.messaging.MessageException  
[BlazeDS] Serializing AMF/HTTP response
```

Comment: Sounds as a mismatch between jars. Can you please post the full stack trace and the blazeds/spring version?

Comment: Your are probably right, Sorry for the delay in replying.
Unfortunately our jars are stripped of their version info.
So, I tried a fresh download and a sample project. The code works.
I will further try to narrow down the jars.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be mismatch in jars. Thank you Cornel Creanga for the initial response.
I also verified that throwing an java.lang.exception was enough to catch the error on the client side.